# Inside the ul tag spans are getting loaded dynamically. So , i want to get query string value of clicked item(span) from breadcrumb.

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code which contain list of breadcrumb
    if i m clicking second item of brCrumb then i want to get querystring from second span that is -?qs= 2

```
        <ul id="BCrumblist" style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0px;" class="breadcrumb"> 
                <span>
                    <a id="dynamicId1" class="TLinks" href="http://sample1?qs=1">test1</a>
                <span class="Bcrumbseparator">&gt;</span>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a id="dynamicId2" class="TLinks" href="http://sample2?qs=2">test2</a>
                <span class="Bcrumbseparator">&gt;</span>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a id="dynamicId3" class="TLinks" href="http://sample3?qs=3">test3</a><span class="Bcrumbseparator">&gt;</span>
                </span>
                <span class="BCrumbCurrentTopic">test4</span>
            </ul>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please have a read of [ask].  You're expected to have at least made an attempt first (and show that attempt here).  If you have zero idea where to start, then please phrase the question to indicate that.  As it is, you've just listed your requirements without explaining which bit you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("ul#BCrumblist span").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(href)
    {
        console.log($(this).find("a").attr("href").split("?")[1]);
    }
});
```